# Ambari setup on top of Hadoop

Tags: apache, hadoop, cluster-computing

I have the following already setup (in order)

1. `A Hadoop 2.5.x - 3 nodes cluster`.
2. `Apache Ambari Version 1.7.0`

So my question is, Is there anyway I can integrate/configure Amabri to monitor my already setup Hadoop cluster ?

Any suggestions/views are much appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

Currently it seems like that's not possible, there is open JIRA ticket on this issue:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMBARI-2852

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is it possible to setup Apache Hadoop distribution (Not the one from Hortonworks) ? If so, what would be the repo URL(Please see the screenshot here https://nimbus.everhelper.me/client/notes/share/139304/PQQNtTGZEoTEqOPyWgUg5UrVyaJ6faz9/ )